# How to Enable Create catalog Option in Integration Services Catalogs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I want to create a SSIS catalog and the way to create a catalog is to right click on "Integration Services Catalogs" node and select "Create Catalog" option.

But "Create Catalog" option is disable , how to enable this option ?

Comment: The catalog uses SQLCLR (the .NET Common Language Runtime(CLR) hosted within SQL Server), so you need to enable CLR on the SQL Server instance before creating a catalog (I have provided the step below for this)

Comment: sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO

Comment: enable it with this script and try again. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: thanks pirvu,i tried your script, but could not get the success. Is there anything else which i am missing

Comment: did you also disconnect it from your SQL instance after running the script?

Comment: yes,I did the same

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

To check if SSIS installed, open Sql Server Configuration Manager, in the SQL Server Services, is something like 'SQL Server Integration Services ' running?

I had this problem and I found the above solution in belew link:
[Can't create a SSISDB catalog due to missing SSISDBBackup.bak file, even though SSIS is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43325488/cant-create-a-ssisdb-catalog-due-to-missing-ssisdbbackup-bak-file-even-though)

Answer (score -1):

Sp_configure 'show advanced options',1;
Go
Reconfigure;
Go
Sp_configure 'clr enabled',1;
Go
Reconfigure
Go

Run the above command from master database