# Can't create a SSISDB catalog due to missing SSISDBBackup.bak file, even though SSIS is installed

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've downloaded SQL Server 2016 standard edition trial along with SSDT in order to test what one can do with a standard edition in SSIS, SSRS, and SSAS.

I also wanted to know whether standard version's SSISDB logging capabilities differs from the one in Enterprise. For this I wanted to create an SSISDB catalog under `Integration Services Catalogs` in SSMS.

When I try to do this, however, I get the error saying that

> The catalog backup file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\binn\SSISDBBackup.bak could not be accessed. Make sure the database file exists, and the SQL server service account is able to access it

From googling this issue it appears as this message shows up whenever someone doesn't have SSIS installed, but I have SSIS on the machine, I've even made a small Project and executed it from within SSIS without any issues just to verify.

I have set this up on `localhost` where I am the admin. Does anyone have any ideas why this won't work?

Regards,

Cenderze

Comment: What did you deploy the project to if there isn't an SSISDB catalog?

Comment: this statement is wrong `I've downloaded SQL Server 2016 standard edition trial along with SSDT ` ssdb wont come  installed, you have to install it

Comment: look out this link  on how to create one :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/create-the-ssis-catalog

Comment: @TheGameiswhar  I mean that I installed SQL server 2016 standard edition along with SSDT as in I installed it separate from SQL server. I downloaded it afterwards "manually". You are right that it was not clear.

Comment: If you go check the path in the error message, what do you see?

Comment: @Rich          I can't deploy the package. I have created a Project and a package in SSIS, but when I try to deploy it I get the error provided in the thread regarding the backup file.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I've checked the path to the file which is the subject of the error, and it is indeed not in the specified folder. Have I misunderstood the SQL license comparisons, is SSISDB not included in SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition?

Comment: @Cenderze You said you have made a small project and deployed it without any issues.

Comment: @Rich          Oh you are right. I meant to say the I've Executed the package, not deployed. I've executed it from within SSIS, and it updated the tables as expected. Will edit the OP!

Comment: Ah yes I see now. You can execute within SSDT without having SSIS installed/running on the server, that is true.

Comment: So looking at the path, do you have a DTS sub folder at all? Do you have a 130 sub folder? Where does it diverge - are you just missing the bak file?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Exactly, I only miss the .bak file.

Comment: @Rich I am facing the same issue.  SSISDBBackup.bak isn't available in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn. Moreover, the 130 folder is also not available in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if SSIS installed, open Sql Server Configuration Manager, in the SQL Server Services, is something like 'SQL Server Integration Services 13.0' running?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. This is strange. By checking SQL Server Confirugration Manager, I saw that SQL Server integration services is indeed not running. How can that be, seeing as I've opened up SSIS, and I have created a Project and a package (but I can't deploy them due to the error of the thread).

Comment: SSIS in SQL Server Data Tools is the development environment and you can open them up and work with them in there, independently of the SSIS service on the server.

Answer (score 3):

Experienced this error message on MS SQL Server 2017.

Resolved by launching MS SQL Server 2017 install media, added Integration Services feature.

After successful installation, when back into SSMS, right-click on Integration Services Catalog for Create Catalog... option.

You will be asked for an encryption password to create the new SSISDB.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this error when I used lower version of SSMS than SSIS. Check if you use proper version of SQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back to the SQL Server installation and check the integration services checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because SQL Integration services is not installed properly with the existing SQL Server you are using.

you can check if SQL Integration services are installed or not by,

Opening --> SQL Server Configuration Manager--> SQL Server Services --> Check if "SQL Server Integeration Services is there"

if its there and if you still get the same issue try re-installing.

Else install the SQL Integration services to your existing SQL Server.

The detailed step to installation is given in this link : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6635/install-ssis/

hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

i installed "Sql Server Integration Services" in my Sql Server 2019, and this solve my problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).